# ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ integer

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I am developing a shoppingcart app, there exists a module to track the order the order using id, and the data is displayed in a datatable.

The DAO function:

```
public List OrderSearch(Integer orderSearchid) {

    List orderDetails = null;
    List itemOrders = new ArrayList();
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Orders.class);
        // Add restriction.
        cr.add(Restrictions.like("orderId", orderSearchid));
        itemOrders = cr.list();
        for (Iterator iterator1 = itemOrders.iterator(); iterator1
                .hasNext();) {
            Orders orders1 = (Orders) iterator1.next();
            System.out.println("*************************");
            System.out.println("Order ID: " + orders1.getOrderId());
            System.out.println("Order NAme: " + orders1.getOrderName());
            System.out.println("Total Price : " + orders1.getTotalPrice());

            orderDetails = orders1.getOrderDetails();
            for (Iterator iterator2 = orderDetails.iterator(); iterator2
                    .hasNext();) {
                OrderDetails orderdetailsnew = (OrderDetails) iterator2
                        .next();
                System.out.println("ORder Details Id : "
                        + orderdetailsnew.getDetailsId());

            }
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return itemOrders;
}
```

orderId is of integer type in the database as well as in the pojo class.
But i am getting an error ,

```
ERROR: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 151
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...........................................................................................

at 

com.shop.hibernate.application.ManageDAO.OrderSearch(ManageDAO.java:292)
        at com.shop.web.ItemDataBean.searchOrder(ItemDataBean.java:407)
```

292: `itemOrders = cr.list()`;
407: `return searchOrders;`

The datatable is empty, no data is being added. Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` with numbers - it's for strings only.

Comment: Yeah got it.. Thanks ..

Comment: Btw for straight forward query why are using Criteria? why con't you use HQL

Comment: i wanted to try it with criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue ..

I had to give :

```
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("orderId", orderSearchid));
```

instead of

```
cr.add(Restrictions.like("orderId", orderSearchid));
```